# How to Create a Custom Slug for Tags and Categories with a prefix or suffix?

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I wanted to rename the slug to use a custom rewrite with a prefix or suffix that I choose. For example, if the tag name is "product" I want to use a rewrite with a slug that says "product-powerpint-ppt" so the final URL will look like /tag/product-powerpoint-ppt instead of /tag/product

I was looking for a solution to this problem from time ago, without relying on htaccess rules, just tweaking WordPress or using a plugin. Anyone had the same question or can advice on a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter `'term_link'`. Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpse_72848_change_tag_slug', 10, 3 );

function wpse_72848_change_tag_slug( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy )
{
    if ( 'post_tag' !== $taxonomy )
        return $termlink;

    if ( 'product' === $term->slug )
        return str_replace( '/product/', '/product-powerpoint-ppt/', $termlink );

    return $termlink;
}
```

Comment: Hi @toscho, this worked straightforward. Thanks. I was able to rewrite the tags and other taxonomies using this snippet. However, when I try to access the url generated, I get a 404 error page. Do you know or have a clue how can I access the correct tag page when I use the link with the suffix? It may exist other similar filter to use.